# Referential integrity constraint violation

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

in my spring-boot application, I have a feature to add multiple animals into a single room. To achieve that I created my entity class like below

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Animal {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_animal_id")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_animal_id")
    Long id;

    @NotEmpty(message = "title should be given")
    String title;

    @CreatedDate
    LocalDateTime located;

    String type;
    Long preference;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "animal")
    Set <Favorite> favoriteRooms;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "room_id")
    Room room;
}
```

below is my room entity:

```
@Entity(name = "room")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Room {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_room_id")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_room_id")
    Long id;

    String title;
    Long size;

    @CreatedDate
    LocalDateTime createdOn;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "rooms")
    Set<Favorite> favorites;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "room")
    Set<Animal> animals;

}
```

Below my service and controller class:

```
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@RequestMapping("/animal")
public class AnimalController {

    AnimalService animalService;

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public AnimalDto addAnimal(@Valid @RequestBody AnimalDto animalDto){
        return animalService.add(animalDto);
    }
}
```

Animal Service

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Slf4j
public class AnimalService {

    AnimalRepository animalRepository;
    RoomRepository roomRepository;
    SourceToDestinationMapper mapper;

    public AnimalDto add(AnimalDto animalDto) {
        Animal animal = mapper.animalDtoToAnimal(animalDto);
        //isValidAnimal(animal);

        Animal savedAnimal = animalRepository.save(animal);
        log.debug("animal object saved:",animal);
        return mapper.animalToAnimalDto(savedAnimal);
    }
}
```

Mapper class:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")

public interface SourceToDestinationMapper {

    Animal animalDtoToAnimal(AnimalDto animal);
    AnimalDto animalToAnimalDto( Animal animal);

    List<AnimalDto> animalsToAnimalDtos(List<Animal> animals);

    Room roomDtoToRoom(RoomDto roomDto);

    RoomDto roomToRoomDto(Room room);
}
```

but if I am trying to add animals in the same room like below

```
{"id":null,
"title":"Zebra",

"type":null,
"preference":null,
"favoriteRooms":null,
"room": {"id": 1,
    "title": "Green",
    "size": 50,
    "createdOn": null,
    "favorites": null,
    "animals": null}
}
```

in my subsequent request to add an animal throws constraint violation exception like below.

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKLCRIG41DUY7EQV30DYTSR4L78: PUBLIC.ANIMAL FOREIGN KEY(ROOM_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.ROOM(ID) (CAST(1 AS BIGINT))"; SQL statement:
insert into animal (located, preference, room_id, title, type, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) [23506-212]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:508) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRowOwnTable(ConstraintReferential.java:311) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRow(ConstraintReferential.java:252) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
    at org.h2.table.Table.fireConstraints(Table.java:1177) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
    at org.h2.table.Table.fireAfterRow(Table.java:1195) ~[h2-2.1.212.jar:2.1.212]
```

Edit 1:
I updated my service class like this. but it is not updating room values:

```
public AnimalDto add(AnimalDto animalDto) throws InvalidRoomDetailException {
        Animal animal = mapper.animalDtoToAnimal(animalDto);
        isValidAnimal(animal);
        Animal savedAnimal = animalRepository.save(animal);
        log.debug("animal object saved:",savedAnimal);
        updateRoomValues(animalDto, savedAnimal);
        return mapper.animalToAnimalDto(savedAnimal);
    }

    private void updateRoomValues(AnimalDto animalDto, Animal savedAnimal) {
        if(animalDto.getRoom() == null)
            return;
        Room room = mapper.roomDtoToRoom(animalDto.getRoom());
        Optional<Room> optionalRoom = roomRepository.findById(room.getId());
        if(optionalRoom.isPresent()){
            Room existingRoom = optionalRoom.get();
            existingRoom.getAnimals().add(savedAnimal);
            roomRepository.save(optionalRoom.get());
            savedAnimal.setRoom(room);
        }
    }
```

Edit 2:
After updating the code I see the below response.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "dog",
    "located": "2022-05-24T18:07:06.4478948",
    "type": null,
    "preference": null,
    "favoriteRooms": null,
    "room": null
}
```

and DB records:

[image]

Comment: **Need more clarification**. Could you please show how are you trying to add that example JSON in your Java code? Which methods or classes are invoked and what do they look like?

Comment: added service and controller class @gsan

Answer (score 1):

##### **`Room` is the owner side of your relationship between `Animal` and `Room` entities -it is a one-to-many relationship anyway-, so you should manage the `Animal` objects in a room by the `Room` side of the relationship.**

What you should do is execute the following steps in the given order:

- Create the `Animal` entity on DB, without any room info, save it & fetch it.
- Get the Room entity that you want to add your Animal entity into (*from db*).
- Add the `Animal` entity into the "*animals*" list of the `Room` entity.
- Update the room entity on DB (*save it as we added the animal into it*)

**Notice that your mapper method should create the `Animal` without any `Room` information.**

### Edit1:

**You should not set `Room` of the `Animal` you have in hand because the managing side is the `Room`.** The following line is not correct and should be removed.

```
savedAnimal.setRoom(room);
```

After all the steps I listed, you should fetch `Animal` entity from DB one last time to get the current state. Your service code will be the following:

```
public AnimalDto add(AnimalDto animalDto) throws InvalidRoomDetailException {
    Animal animal = mapper.animalDtoToAnimal(animalDto);
    isValidAnimal(animal);
    animal = animalRepository.save(animal);
    log.debug("animal object saved:",savedAnimal);
    updateRoomValues(animalDto, savedAnimal);
    animal = animalRepository.findById(animal.getId());
    return mapper.animalToAnimalDto(animal);
}

private void updateRoomValues(AnimalDto animalDto, Animal savedAnimal) {
    if(animalDto.getRoom() == null)
        return;
    Room room = mapper.roomDtoToRoom(animalDto.getRoom());
    Optional<Room> optionalRoom = roomRepository.findById(room.getId());
    if(optionalRoom.isPresent()){
        Room existingRoom = optionalRoom.get();
        existingRoom.getAnimals().add(savedAnimal);
        roomRepository.save(optionalRoom.get());
    }
}
```

Comment: so I don't need to change cascading type right?

Comment: You don't need to change it, just use it as default if you do not want different configurations about cascading. If the answer solves the problem, you can mark it as *accepted answer* for people who will face the same issue in the future.

Comment: how do I tell the mapper to exclude this?

Comment: Could you edit the question and share your mapper as well?

Comment: added mapper class, I am using MapStruct

Comment: `@Mapping(ignore = true, source = "room", target = "room")`

Add this annotation above the  `animalDtoToAnimal` method in order to ignore the field `room`

Comment: I am testing it,once I get results, will updatee

Comment: it is not adding into room ..updating my question

Comment: I edited the original answer according to your requirements

Comment: hey, that is not exactly producing the same result, as it is not storing room details on the animal table, and animal details in-room table. will update my question

Comment: So issue was there due to my cascadingType selection. I had to make to all